# Am I ok to switch to SIMPLE recovery in these circumstances?

Tags: sql, database-backups, recovery

The database I have taken over has an extremely large log file (mdf is 6gb ldf is 185gb). Every night a scheduled task creates a .bak file. In our environment, it would be acceptable to roll back to the previous night/morning.

With this in mind, would it be ok to switch to SIMPLE recovery?

Comment: 1) This is probably not the right forum: I'd suggest superuser.com instead.  2) There is no simple "Yes/No" answer.  You need to address a) exactly why is the logfile growing so large, b) can the application be optimized, and c) what is the potential business impact on truncating the log.

Comment: If you don't need your transaction logs after the transaction, then I would say Yes.

Comment: @paulsm4 I presume the log is so large because it is in full recovery but the log has never been backed up? As for C) what sort of potential issues would it raise for a hypothetical business? I understand that simple = no point in time recovery, but if a .bak file existed for opening of business that day and rollback to then was fine, isnt that ok? Thanks

Comment: "The log has never been backed up".  Whoops!  Do a backup *ASAP*!  And yeah, it sounds like the "simple recovery model" is probably the best backup for your needs.

Comment: @paulsm4 I mean the log by itself has not been backed up. Full backups (*.bak files) are taken each night. Isn't that reasonably ok or cause for concern?